# Configure jackrabbit with jndi

Tags: java, jndi, jackrabbit, drools-guvnor

I'm trying to configure jackrabbit's file system and persistence manager through jndi as follows (`repository.xml`):

```
<PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.MSSqlPersistenceManager">
    <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
    <param name="url" value="java:/jdbc/MY_DATASOURCE/default"/>
    <param name="schema" value="mssql"/>
    <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="jcr_pm_"/>
</PersistenceManager>

<FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DbFileSystem">
    <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
    <param name="url" value="java:/jdbc/MY_DATASOURCE/default"/>
    <param name="schema" value="mssql"/>
    <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="jcr_fs_"/>
</FileSystem>
```

when I start my server I get the following exception:

```
16:34:09,209 INFO  [STDOUT] 2013-12-03 16:34:09,205 ERROR [org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DbFileSystem] failed to initialize file system
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for java:/jdbc/MY_DATASOURCE/default
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DbFileSystem.getConnection(DbFileSystem.java:187)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DatabaseFileSystem.initConnection(DatabaseFileSystem.java:956)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DatabaseFileSystem.init(DatabaseFileSystem.java:175)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.FileSystemConfig.createFileSystem(FileSystemConfig.java:47)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.<init>(RepositoryImpl.java:244)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.create(RepositoryImpl.java:557)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository$2.getRepository(TransientRepository.java:245)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository.startRepository(TransientRepository.java:265)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository.login(TransientRepository.java:333)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository.login(TransientRepository.java:363)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.repository.BRMSRepositoryConfiguration.newSession(BRMSRepositoryConfiguration.java:112)
```

the version of jackrabbit is 1.4
jackrabbit does not seem to like jndi configuration. I also tried with `url=jdbc/MY_DATASOURCE/default` but i get the same error

Comment: That doesn't look like an sqlserver JDBC URL. That's what Java is trying to tell you - there is no driver on the classpath that understands that JDBC URL. Likely you are using placeholder data and you need to replace it with the proper DBMS specific JDBC URL.

Comment: @Gimby the [jackrabbit documentation](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/1.5/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/fs/db/DbFileSystem.html) states that jndi can be used instead of a JDBC URL with InitialContext as a driver

Comment: Have you tested that your datasource is set up correctly? Is the MySQL Driver available on the class path? The JackRabbit configuration looks correct which make me think it is an issue with the datasource.

Comment: I think this version of Jackrabbit does not support data sources. If you need this feature, I suggest to upgrade to a more recent version of Jackrabbit (2.x)

Comment: @lucasweb yes my datasource is configured correctly.
@ThomasMueller thats what I start to think, unfortunately I'm not allowed to upgrade that library (legacy code). From 1.4 javadoc, there is a [JNDIDatabaseFileSystem](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/1.4/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/fs/db/JNDIDatabaseFileSystem.html) and a [JNDIDatabasePersistenceManager](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/1.4/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/persistence/db/JNDIDatabasePersistenceManager.html) configurable with property `dataSourceLocation` instead of `url` but then I have a NullPointerException. Any thoughts?